# Python Error 'list index out of range' When Using Split Function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im am trying to pull info from yahoo finance using urllib2 and then using the split function to display the Net Income. When I go to run the program in the Python 2.7.12 shell I have to print the command "yahooNetIncome('')" with the stock symbol in the single quotes. Whenever I do this it comes up with the error "failed in main loop list index out of range". Im rather new to python so I do not fully understand the problem. If someone could please help that would be greatly appreciated.

```
import time
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen

stock = ['a', 'aa', 'aapl', 'abbv', 'abc', 'abt', 'ace', 'aci', 'acn', 'act', 'adbe', 'adi', 'adm', 'adp']

def yahooNetIncome(stock):
   try:
        sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + stock + '/financials').read()
        NI = sourceCode.split('<span data-reactid=".1vqhh4ora92.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.0.2.0.2:1:$INCOME_STATEMENT.0.0.$GROSS_PROFIT.1:$0.0.0">')[1].split('</span>')[0]
        print 'Net Income: ', NI
    except Exception, e:
        print 'failed in main loop', str(e)
```

Comment: Either the first split command is returning a list of length < 2 or the second is returning an empty list. You should probably use a dedicated HTML parser like BeautifulSoup rather than trying to use the split function on HTML elements that may be dynamic as you're doing now.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting bitten by a couple of things.

The out-of-range error you're getting is due to there being nothing in the list that you're trying to get the zeroth element of in your `NI` assignment line. That list is empty because the `split()` call is failing, and it's failing because the string you're feeding into it doesn't exist in the data pulled from the URL. This is the smaller issue.

You're probably wondering why that string isn't in there when you can see it pretty clearly with a browser inspector. Here's where you're getting bitten by the bigger issue: the page you're downloading dynamically changes its content via JavaScript. If you use a tool like Curl to dump it straight out to disk without executing JavaScript you'll see that the string you're searching on doesn't exist within the file. Worse, the string you're trying to fetch (the number that you want to assign `NI` to) doesn't exist either. The JavaScript must be run before it gets displayed. In your browser you're seeing a live display after the JavaScript has been run. When you're pulling in the page via Python (or Curl or any other tool that doesn't behave like a browser and run JavaScript the way the page expects) you won't get the data you're looking for.

Quite possibly this is being done by the site owner specifically to prevent the sort of thing you're trying to do.

Comment: Code you show me what the code should look like or is what Im trying to accomplish impossible?

Comment: @R.Orford There is no simple answer. You'd have to mimic the actions of a browser, or automate a browser to go to the page and dump the rendered version. If you deviate too far from a regular browser the numbers that you're looking for won't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Your list index out of range means that your call to the `split()` method didn't find anything to split on.  Therefore, there wouldn't be an index `1` (no splits, only one index), causing a list index out of range error to be thrown.

Comment: @R.Orford to do that, I would have to comb through the HTML code of the page, which I'm not going to do for you.